# Anylogic - <unknown> (GISRoute) : The length is zero

Tags: gis, anylogic

I tried to make a flood network, but I have a problem while running it.
please check the problem below.

> (GISRoute) : The length is zerojava.lang.RuntimeException: root:
>
> (GISRoute) : The length is zero
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISMarkupElement.error(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISRoute$1.j(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractCurve.initialize(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISRoute.doInitialize(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.AbstractMarkup.initializeInternal(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISMarkupElement.initialize(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.markup.GISRoute.(Unknown Source)
>
> at floodmodelv1.Main.floodFunction(Main.java:662)
>
> at floodmodelv1.Main.executeActionOf(Main.java:278)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.i(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.nf(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.j(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$f.run(Unknown Source)

Would you please help me?

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4z4kpycp75nwx4g/AABnqWGa5p2kYGAUo1W4ZSU6a?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your floodfunction you do:

```
x1=x2;
y1=y2;
```

This means that the second time your floodFunction is executed, point1 and point2 will be the same, which means that the segment you construct will be constructed with 2 points that are the same, and a segment needs to have a length greater than 0.